# Using the JSON response from 3rd party api with geodjango

Tags: json, django, api, geodjango

I am try to create a way to narrow down posts on a django app by location & radius. The way I am trying to do this is:

- Use 3rd party (OpenCage) API to convert location to lat / lng
- Gather the JSON response, filter for the most correct one (first response in US)
- Use the response lat & lng to filter listings via GIS

What I have done is successfully connect to the API, and get a lat & lng back, however I am having to filter the response in my templates rather than in my models. I have also found the following which appears to be the solution needed for narrowing results in a radius:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from django.contrib.gis.measure import Distance  


lat = 52.5
lng = 1.0
radius = 10
point = Point(lng, lat)    
Place.objects.filter(location__distance_lt=(point, Distance(km=radius)))
```

What I need to solve, and am hoping for your help with is how do I

1. filter the api responses and only get what I need from them (components country, geometry lat, geometry lng)
2. gather the lat & lng for use in the above code?

views.py

```
from posts import services


def search(request):
    queryset_list = posts.objects.order_by('id')
    if 'location' in request.GET:
        q = request.GET['location']
        locations_list = services.get_location(q)
        context = {
            'posts': queryset_list,
            'locations_list': locations_list
        }
    return render(request, 'posts/search.html', context)
```

services.py

```
import requests

def get_location(location):
    url = 'https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json'
    params = {'q': location, 'key': '###', 'language': 'en', 'pretty': 1}
    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    locations = r.json()
    return locations
```

Comment: Do you really need to consume that api in the backend? I think this should go in the frontend so resources do not pull your server but the client. When you need to save something then pass it to the backend.

Comment: @Jota I think you're right, however I do need to filter the stored postings using the results from the API, I am open to a completely different direction where I more efficiently reach the desired results

Comment: If you have a graphic interface you have to do the search and get_location in your frontend in AJAX, for example. When the API responds, filter the attributes of the JSON and then pass it to the backend.

Comment: @Jota so I could just pass the lat and lng attributes from the JSON to the radius script above asynchronously and skip the mess and save the user a reload? I've been approaching this from a django perspective and completely tuned out client side

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try like this(Based on demo JSON response provided by OpenCage):

```
import requests
from django.db.models import Q

def get_location(location):
    url = 'https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json'
    params = {'q': location, 'key': '###', 'language': 'en', 'pretty': 1}
    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    locations = r.json()
    filter_query = Q()
    radius = 10
    for item in locations.get('results', []):
         geo = item.get('geometry')
         lat = geo.get('lat')
         lng = geo.get('lng')
         point = Point(lng, lat)    
         filter_query |= Q(location__distance_lt=(point, Distance(km=radius)))
    return Place.objects.filter(filter_query)
```